# IBM Domino - delete shared view & convert NSF application to NTF (template)

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a very simple IBM Domino database with an XPages Java application and nothing else inside, I want to export it  as a template (ntf) instead of a database. If I just rename the nsf file with `ntf` extension, I can see the template in the application list when trying to create a new application, but it's icon is still a database icon and not the green template one. I tried searching online and looking through designer/admin options but found nothing that would help me.

Another question is, in the nsf I have one blank view and it's being displayed every time I open the application, I want to get rid of this view but I'm getting an error that I cannot delete the last shared view. It's annoying me because when opening the application for the first time it's being shown together with my about page, despite the launch options in application configuration are set to only display the "about" page.

How can I achieve these two things in IBM Domino 10?

Comment: There has to be at least one view in a Notes db.  Make a Page document to open for the db rather than the About doc.

Answer (score 3):

In order for your application to be recognized as a template you need to set a template name on the design tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to Per Henrik's recommendation, if you want to create a template, you need to create a new copy of the database and select to only copy the design elements and then use the NTF extension to createa template instead of the NSF.

With your Launch settings, you've only selected to open the About document by default every time the database is opened, you're not "only" opening the About document. The shared view is still being opened behind the About doc and you can't get rid of the only view. If you don't want users accessing the database via the Notes client, in order to avoid the view being opened, you might look at creating a Frameset that opens one Page that tells users to use the Web view. On the web side, you'll want to set the XPage that should be opened when accessing it via a browser.

Comment: I did it like this, but the outcome is that I still have a file with NTF extension, but in Domino it's being shown with a database (blue square) icon, instead of the green one that all templates have. I set my NSF's design as master template and set it's template name, then I made a new copy form it and selected to only copy design, set the extension manually to NTF. I even set the  NTF file itself to be a master template but it still was shown as a database (and was listed under databases in server)